# Need to install Python Pint Package using MSYS

Tags: python, fortran, msys, pint

I am very new to using MSYS and I need it to run a Fortran based code through python interface. I followed the whole installation procedure in this link
https://github.com/SINTEF/thermopack/blob/main/addon/pycThermopack/README.md
and when I tried to install Python Pint package I kept getting this error:
[MSYS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX9gt.png)

It seems that this package is very important to run the GUI correctly. What did I miss here? Is there any other way to install this package?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8lBS.png)

I managed to install it by installing Pip command using

$ pacman -S python3-pip

$ pip3 install --upgrade pip

pip install Pint

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).